# Can I use brotli compression with nginx without compiling anything?

Tags: nginx

I want to use brotli compression with nginx on Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't want to install all of the development and build packages or compile anything on our production severs.

Can it be done? Is there some package that can be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `nginx` [manual](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/brotli/) you need to install `nginx-plus-module-brotli` package:

```
apt-get install nginx-plus-module-brotli
```

and in `nginx.conf` you need to add those lines:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;
```

Additionally you need to config this module. For example:

```
brotli on;
brotli_comp_level 1;
brotli_types text/plain text/css;
```

Check out [all the directives](https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli/blob/master/README.md) you can use in config.

Comment: Note that NGINX Plus is not open source and [requires a subscription](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-plus/#prerequisites) (contrary to NGINX which is shipped by Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

Since brotli is part of Nginx Plus subscription, there isn't a way to avoid compiling nginx yourself.

I use Debian myself, and my approach is the following:

1. Add nginx.org Debian repository to my development machine.
2. `apt-get source nginx` to download the sources
3. Add brotli and other customisations
4. Use `dpkg-buildpackage` to build a `.deb` package.
5. Deploy the `.deb` package on production servers.

You don't need to use nginx.org repository, you can also do this with the OS own repository.